# How to avoid putting quotes around numbers with Perl JSON module?

Tags: json, perl, google-visualization

Is there please a way to make the `encode_json` method NOT to put quotes around numbers?

For example I'm using perl 5.10 on CentOS 6.3 (and also ActiveState perl 5.16 on Win 7) and it puts the quotes where it shouldn't:

```
# perl -MJSON -e 'print encode_json({a => [split(",", "1.2,30")]});'
{"a":["1.2","30"]}
```

That is, ok yes, it sees the "1.2" and "30" as strings in the code above, but my problem is:

My perl script parses CSV-files and generate HTML-files [using Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datatables_dataview) and the latter are confused by having quotes around number-values (eventhough I told them that the column is of type "numeric").

As a workaround I iterate through my data stracture and replace every number by `sprintf "%f", $val` but this results in too many nulls being displayed after each number, which makes the charts correct, but ugly looking:

```
# perl -e 'printf "%f", "30"'
30.000000
```

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Yes, adding a zero or multiplying by one *seems to work* at the first glance:

```
# perl -MJSON -e 'print encode_json({a => [map {1 * $_} split(",", "1.2,30")]});'
{"a":[1.2,30]}
```

but in [my real script](http://pastebin.com/3sn6yPaD) it still **doesn't work for the floating numbers**.

And you can see the problem I still have at the CLI when using Dumper module too:

```
# perl -MData::Dumper -e 'print Dumper({a => [map {1.0 * $_} split(",", "1.2,30")]});'
$VAR1 = {
          'a' => [
                   '1.2', # <= THIS IS MY PROBLEM AND CONFUSES GOOGLE CHARTS
                   30
                 ]
        };
```

Comment: Dumper always adds quotes for floating point numbers, so that's totally meaningless.

Comment: If that code works and not your "real script", it's cause you do something different in your "real script"!

Comment: My real script at http://pastebin.com/3sn6yPaD does little besides calling `split` on CSV lines and then `encode_json`. And the latter adds quotes around float values and no workaround has helped there yet.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your problem is that although you're correctly converting it to a number, it's getting converted back to a string before you call encode_json.  This is because you're calling Data::Dumper on it in a debug statement.   If you comment out your call to Data::Dumper, you'll find encode_json outputs the right thing.

e.g. this example shows the JSON object before and after calling Dumper on the object:

```
$ perl -MData::Dumper -MJSON -e '
my $obj = {a => [map { $_ - 0 } split(",", "1.2,30")]};
print "JSON before: ",encode_json($obj),"\n";
print "Dumper: ",Dumper($obj);
print "JSON after: ",encode_json($obj),"\n";
'
JSON before: {"a":[1.2,30]}
Dumper: $VAR1 = {
          'a' => [
                   '1.2',
                   30
                 ]
        };
JSON after: {"a":["1.2",30]}
```

as you can see, Dumper actually modifies the object you're dumping, affecting your subsequent encode_json call.

Comment: Thank you.  Dumper was my problem as well.  I never suspected a supposedly read-only action was modifying its input.

Comment: I had the exact same problem... and I am also shocked that Data::Dumper is modifying its arguments!!

Answer (score 11):

You already have your answer for this, but I wanted to point out the idiomatic way to do this in Perl. From [chapter 10 of Modern Perl](http://modernperlbooks.com/books/modern_perl/chapter_10.html#VW5hcnlDb2VyY2lvbnM):

> To ensure that Perl treats a value as numeric, add zero:
>
> ```
> my $numeric_value = 0 + $value;
> ```
>
> To ensure that Perl treats a value as boolean, double negate it:
>
> ```
> my $boolean_value = !! $value;
> ```
>
> To ensure that Perl treats a value as a string, concatenate it with the empty string:
>
> ```
> my $string_value = '' . $value;
> ```

Comment: I just wanted to leave a note here since I had a lot of trouble with this implementation. If you are adding 0 or multiplying by 1 to turn your string into a numeric value and then JSON encoding it please use the newest version of JSON::XS. There are certain cases where you can use this trick and the JSON encoding will still result in a string being shown.

Answer (score 6):

They are coming out as strings because you get strings out of `split`.

There might be a nicer way to do it, but multiplying them by 1 appears to work:

```
perl -MJSON -e 'print encode_json({a => [map { $_ * 1  } split(",", "1.2,30")]});'
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for floating number for some reason. And I have tried `+0.0` and `*1.0` too

Comment: I get `{"a":[1.2,30]}` as the output of that, so it works on floating numbers for me. Perhaps you have an older version of the JSON module?

Comment: No, but thank you all for the help. I will investigate further, maybe go for JavaScript solution: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-visualization-api/EUXBop_HQ5M

Comment: Alexander - see my answer for an explanation of why your floating point numbers are emitted in quotes.

Answer (score 3):

Perl keeps track of scalar datatypes internally. You can force the type of the scalar into a number by using it in an arithmetic expression. For example:

```
my $scalar = "3.14"; # $scalar is a string
$scalar *= 1;        # Now $scalar is a number
```

On the other hand, if your problem is having too many zeroes in the output of `sprintf`, you can fix that by changing the precision to something else, for example 2 digits:

```
sprintf "%.2f", $val
```

Comment: or `sprintf "%g",...` and let Perl worry about how many digits to display

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar case. My perl code generates (in a complicated way) a complicated data structure, then serializes it with JSON::to_json and passes it to javascript. There're a lot of numbers on different depth in the data structure, and javascript will do arithmetic on them.

'+' in javascript works as addition for numbers and as concatenation for strings, so it's critically important not to put numbers in quotes when converting them to json. 
On the other hand, the data is quite complex, so I need simple and universal way to force numbers be numbers in arbitrary array/hash/array of hashes etc.

So, I ended up with function like this:

```
use Scalar::Util qw(looks_like_number);
sub force_numbers
{  
    if (ref $_[0] eq ""){
        if ( looks_like_number($_[0]) ){
            $_[0] += 0;
        }   
    } elsif ( ref $_[0] eq 'ARRAY' ){
        force_numbers($_) for @{$_[0]};
    } elsif ( ref $_[0] eq 'HASH' ) {
        force_numbers($_) for values %{$_[0]};
    }   

    return $_[0];
}
```

Now I can apply it before converting data to json:

```
print to_json(force_numbers($data));
```

Answer (score 0):

The *correct* solution has already been given.

If for any reason you find it difficult to adopt, here is an even easier suggestion, thanks to `Data::Dump` which does all the hard work for us:

```
perl -MJSON -MData::Dump=pp -le 'print encode_json eval pp { a => [split /,/, "1.2,30,b"] }'
```

which gives:

```
{"a":[1.2,30,"b"]}
```

If your efficiency constraints permit to afford the `pp`/`eval` roundtrip, it should solve your problem almost transparently.

It also spots that the quoted reals you obtained in your tests were due only to a `Data::Dumper` (questionable) choice, as already said by others.

Comment: My real script at http://pastebin.com/3sn6yPaD doesn't use Data::Dumper for generating the string.

Comment: I was referring to the test shown at the bottom of your original post, where you use `Data::Dumper` to dump your data structure after the split (I was blaming `Data::Dumper` for its *questionable choice* to quote the reals).
Anyway, your script can just use `pp`/`eval` before `encode_json` (as shown in my one-liner) and your problems should disappear.